# How to install ant's build.xml file using existing ant libraries?

Tags: xml, ant, redhat

I have a project which is supposed to be installed in Redhat 6.7. It has it's own ant libraries in lib folder. Libraries is shown in the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFS6u.png)

I have an install script which triggers build.xml file. And the content of the script is as follows:

```
OLD_DIR=$(pwd)
SCRIPT_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)
cd ${SCRIPT_DIR}

set ANT_HOME=$SCRIPT_DIR/ant
set ANT_LIB=${ANT_HOME}/lib

set PATH=${ANT_HOME}/bin:${ANT_LIB}:${PATH}

${ANT_HOME}/bin/ant -q -e

cd ${OLD_DIR}
exit 0
```

After installing through the install script i am getting,

```
BUILD FAILED

XML parser factory has not been configured correctly: Provider for class javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be created
```

I think that it is causing due to pre-installed ant in redhat 6.7 but i am not sure about it.

Comment: I think it might be due to a typo in your shell script. See the `set NT_LIB` line.

Comment: Is ANT installed properly? Is there evidence that this is a problem with ANT or a missing dependency in your code's build logic? (My point is that a build should be constructing it's own classpath and not relying on the classpath of the ANT installation)

Comment: @MarkO'Connor yes, you are correct about that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was the problem in java classpath. Fixing that solved the issue.